# How to print a Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

I am making a simple resume generation app.

**Index.js:**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Resume from "../components/resume";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";

const App = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => componentRef.current
  });

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-6">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="bg-gray-500 border border-gray-500 p-2 mb-4"
        onClick={handlePrint}
      >
        {" "}
        Print Resume{" "}
      </button>
      <Resume ref={componentRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The resume gets generated from the `components/resume.js` file and it is a **functional component**..

I am using the [**react-to-print**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) library to print the resume component alone.

Also took the reference from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rzdhd) ..

But in my application, If I click the `Print Resume` , then the resume doesn't gets printed..

Instead I get the following warnings,

> **Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
> this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?**

and another warning as,

> For "react-to-print" to work only Class based components can be
> printed.

**Complete Working Example:**

> **https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-react-sandbox-forked-uivc8**

Please try clicking the `Print Resume` button in the above link where it doesn't print the resume.

Could you please help me to print the generated resume? Thanks in advance..

Comment: do you want to convert your components to class based instead of function based?

Comment: No, I need to have it as functional component alone.. Is it not possible to make in functional component?

Comment: But I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print#calling-from-functional-components-with-usereacttoprint this one only which is related to functional component..

Comment: okay i see i try it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to use `React.forwardRef()`

```
const Resume = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  // ...

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-6" ref={ref}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
})
```

Forked codesandbox

[image: Edit Tailwind React Sandbox (forked)]

Answer (score 2):

The component you want to print will still need to be a class component so I converted the `Resume` component to a class component.

If you try using this as ref to pring `<h1 ref={componentRef}>HELLO?</h1>` that will work even though a simple h1 tag is not class based component.

Try this on this edited [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-react-sandbox-forked-u932z?file=/src/index.js) of yours.

If you want a solid functional component you can migrate the `Resume` component as the child of `<div ref={componentRef} />`.

Comment: It works in functional component itself.. Thanks for your try and help..